# Android : Scraping articles with jsoup

Tags: java, android, kotlin, jsoup, screen-scraping

First, let's sum up what I'm trying to do. I'm building an android app for my school which basically scrapes articles my school posts on its website and first lists them in a recyclerview and then you can read them in a detailed view.

For the scraping part, I use Jsoup. I got the detailed view done, and the recycleview too. Everything works fine without the scraping part.

When I scrape a single article to the detailed view, it works without problems. The problem is when I'm trying to scrape all titles of the webpage and displaying them into my recyclerview.

Here's a screenshot of what I'm trying to scrape and my code :

[Webpage source annotated screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwGcp.png)

I'm trying to get all the titles and urls.
Here's a part of the website's code, I need what's in the spans with "font-size:1em;" and the href link.

```
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3" class="derniers3articles" style="height:250px;">
  <a href="https://legymnase.eu/2017/11/frum-franco-allemand/" style="text-decoration:none;">
    <figure class="mini_img"><img src="https://legymnase.eu/cms/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/forumff-250x150.jpg" width="250" height="150" alt="" class="image3derniers arrondie"></figure>
    <span style="color:grey;">20-Nov-2017</span><br>
    <span style="font-size:1em;">Forum franco-allemand</span>
  </a>
```

18-Nov-2017
        Les élèves de 1ES, de futurs citoyens ...
      
  
  
      
        
        14-Nov-2017
        Ventes de gâteaux afin de financer le ...

Here's my code :

```
class LyceeList : AppCompatActivity() {

var titles = ArrayList<String>()
var urls = ArrayList<String>()
var articles = ArrayList<Article>()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lycee)

    val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.lyceeRecycler) as RecyclerView

    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayout.VERTICAL, false)

    val recupArticles: AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>? = RecupArticles().execute()


    for (i in 0 until urls.size) {
        articles.add(Article(urls[i], titles[i]))
    }

    val adapter = LyceeAdapter(articles)

    recyclerView.adapter = adapter

}

inner class RecupArticles : AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {



    override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: Void?): Void? {
        try {
            var doc: Document = Jsoup.connect("https://legymnase.eu/lycee/").get()
            val titlesElement : Elements = doc.select("div.derniers3articles > span")
            val urlsProvisory : Elements = doc.select("div.derniers3articles > a")
            val urlsElement : Elements = doc.select("a[href]")


            for (i in 0 until titlesElement.size) {
                titles[i] = titlesElement.get(i).text()
            }

            for (i in 0 until urlsElement.size) {
                urls[i] = urlsElement.get(i).text()
            }


        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return null
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: Void?) {
        super.onPostExecute(result)

    }

}
```

}

If I manually add an Article like .add(Article("Testurl", "TestTitle") it does show up in the recyclerview. But these don't. After several tests, I feel like in my loop in onCreate, the arrays are empty... Have you got any ideas please?

Also, another secondary problem : How can I implement the onclicklistener on the single cardviews to send the URL to the "articleDetail" activity and open it up? Should I put the url as extra to the intent? (this question is secundary, the first one is the one to solve.)

Thanks very much in advance !

Comment: If there is an RSS feed that's better to use

Comment: I wanted to, but there is no RSS feed...

Comment: paste your html content instead of putting screenshots, it will be easier for us to help you

Comment: Just edited, I added the code!